# How to avoid Collection.sort() method from executing in a test case?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Hi I am writing unit test cases for a program. In that program I am testing a certain method in which their is this method :  Collections.sort(Arraylist object).
Its something like this.

```
public void abc(){ 
  try{ 
   Arraylist<object_class> object=some_method.get(list);
   Collections.sort(object); 
   System.out.print("The whole functon is executing successfully") }
   catch(exception e)   { 
         system.out.print("error message")  } }
```

the some_method.get(list)` method I am calling is sending a empty list so when Collections.sort() is called it goes to catch block and the rest code is not executed.
What can i do so that this Collections.sort() method is not called while test case is running.

PS- above code is only to explain the question and I cant make changes to main class

In test class I tried to use this method

Mockito.doNothing().when(collections.sort(Mockito.anyList()));//this is not working

So I tried this Mockito.doNothing().when(collections.class).sort(Mockito.anyList()); //this is also not working

I can return a mock list to object but I want to know if I can prevent Collections.sort() from executing.

Please help

Comment: Hint: please turn to the help center and read how to properly format source code in your questions. You dont want all those `>` in there for example!

Answer (score 2):

It' simple if you want to execute Collections.sort() without any exception follow below steps:

1) Create a list object with dummy values in your test class and send it to main class

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
```

2) Second step is make sure that your

```
some_method.get(list);
```

returns a ArrayList of objects,

3) As Collections class has static method sort, JVM will execute rest of the code as usual. And will not through any exception.

PS- If Mockito.doNothing() is not working try with PowerMockito.doNothing(), it might work and make sure that you have

1) @PrepareforTest(Collections.class)

2) PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);

3) PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Collections.sort(obj));

Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong on many levels:

1. You are using a **raw** type there (by using ArrayList **without** a generic type parameter) - never do that!
2. If your test setup makes that other method return null, then don't manipulate "later" code - instead either avoid that **null** or make sure your production code can deal with it!

In other words: there are only two reasonable choices:

A) if in reality, that method **never** returns null. Then you should make sure, that this is also true for your **test** setup.

B) if in reality, that method returns null, too ... then your production code needs to deal with that, for example by doing a null check before calling sort!

Finally: especially for lists, that problem really **doesn't exist** at all: the answer is - you **never** ever return null! Instead, you return an **empty** list if there is no data. Empty lists can be sorted without a problem! Long story short: avoid returning **null** in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> I can return a mock list to object but I want to know if I can prevent Collections.sort() from executing.

I don't see a way to prevent that
`Collections.sort()` is executed as long as the method that calls it is executed and as long as you can't change the tested code. The reason is that `sort` is a static method. You can pass or inject an instance that is a mock to achieve your goal.

Returning a mock list that can be sorted is the way to go in my opinion. If you manipulate the behavior of the tested class during test you will have a higher risk not to find errors. Additionally, you have a tight coupling between test and tested class in this case.